# Is there any simple way to solve $366^n(366-n)!\geq 2\times 366!$?

Tags: inequality

I am teaching probability for junior high school students. On the last page there is a "challenge yourself" section asking

> What is the least number of students in a classroom for the probability that at least two of them have their birthday falling on the same day of the year to be greater than $1/2$?

It leads to an inequality $366^n(366-n)!\geq 2\times 366!$. I have solved it with program as follows.

[image]

The answer is 23 students.

## Question

I wonder whether there is another simpler way to solve it for junior high school students with pencil and paper only.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: This inequality is hard to solve explicitly, logarithms don't help much. Ways to go around the problem is to use an approximative model which yields good approximate results (fine enough since n is an integer). All presentations of this material that I've seen reference a table similar to yours.

Comment: If I had to attack this by hand, I'd convert the factorial on the left to a Gamma function and try to see if calculus would help to find roots. I wouldn't be too optimistic though, and besides, I doubt any of your junior high students know calculus.

Comment: I think I have to reduce the number by asking "What is the least number of students in a classroom for the probability that at least two of them have the same blood type to be greater than 1/2?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic-geometric inequality tells us
$$\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\le\left(N-\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^n $$
and is quite sharp when $n\ll N$. Thus a good approximation for $n$ might be the solution of
$$N^n=2\cdot \left(N-\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^n,$$
or:
$$\left(1-\frac{n-1}{2N}\right)^n \approx \frac 12$$
With $c:=n^2/N$ and for $n\gg 1$,
$$\left(1-\frac{n-1}{2N}\right)^n\approx\left(1-\frac c{2n}\right)^n\approx e^{-\frac c2}.$$
This suggests $c\approx 2\ln 2$ and so $n\approx \sqrt{2N\ln 2}$. With $N=366$, this crude approximation gives us $n\approx 22.53$.